# Implementing open-graph social share in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, facebook-opengraph, socialshare

I am working on a question web-app which has 20 posts on a single page. I have to implement facebook share button on each question. I am using meta og:image. However, for sharing each single post, og:image content will have to be changed, but FB doesnot seem to read changes through javascript. As a result, questions within image post is not visible. What are the ways to implement dynamic meta tags so that the images are visible during fb sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript will be ignored by Facebook, the usual solution is SSR (server side rendering) or something like https://prerender.io/ - you have to make sure each post has a static link.

I am using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) with SSR for that, and can only recommend it. Another solution would be [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/), for example.

Comment: what about using nextjs with react for server side rendering. Will it solve this issue?

Comment: i am using next.js with SSR for that (and other things), yes.